# SSIS DTS Script Task has encountered an exception in user code

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssis

I'm trying to execute an SSIS package with a scripting component in Visual Basic 2010. I get the following error when I execute the package:

[image]

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Custom Code starts here
        /*
         * Description: Reads the input CMI Stats files and converts into a more readable format
         * This Code for Better CMI Parser is converted as per SC's original code by S.A. on 3/6/2014
         * Here is the description from original procedure
         * CustType = DOMESTIC/INTERNATIONAL/ETC
         * CategoryType = SBU/MAN
         * Category = Actual value (AI/CC/etc)
         * DataType = INCOMING or SHIP (or something else later?)
         * 
         * 3/23/2010
         * Uncommented the CAD file load....
         */
        string[,] filesToProcess = new string[2, 2] { {(String)Dts.Variables["csvFileNameUSD"].Value,"USD" }, {(String)Dts.Variables["csvFileNameCAD"].Value,"CAD" } };
        string headline = "CustType,CategoryType,CategoryValue,DataType,Stock QTY,Stock Value,Floor QTY,Floor Value,Order Count,Currency";
        string outPutFile = Dts.Variables["outputFile"].Value.ToString();
        //Declare Output files to write to
        FileStream sw = new System.IO.FileStream(outPutFile, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(sw);
        w.WriteLine(headline);
        
        //Loop Through the files one by one and write to output Files
        for (int x = 0; x < filesToProcess.GetLength(1); x++)
        {                
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filesToProcess[x, 0]))
            {
                string categoryType = "";
                string custType = "";
                string dataType = "";
                string categoryValue = "";

                //Read the input file in memory and close after done
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filesToProcess[x, 0]);
                string fileText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                string[] lines = fileText.Split(Convert.ToString(System.Environment.NewLine).ToCharArray());
                sr.Close();                                        

                //Read String line by line and write the lines with params from sub headers
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    if (line.Split(',').Length > 3)
                    {
                        string lineWrite = "";
                        lineWrite = line;
                        string[] cols = line.Split(',');
                        if (HeaderLine(cols[1]))
                        {
                            string[] llist = cols[0].Split();
                            categoryType = llist[llist.Length - 1];
                            custType = llist[0];
                            dataType = llist[1];
                            if (dataType == "COMPANY")
                            {
                                custType = llist[0] + " " + llist[1];
                                dataType = llist[2];
                            }
                        }
                        if (cols[0].Contains("GRAND"))
                        {
                            categoryValue = "Total";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string[] col0 = cols[0].Split(' ');
                            categoryValue = col0[col0.Length - 1];
                        }
                        int z = 0;
                        string[] vals = new string[cols.Length];
                        for (int i = 1; i < cols.Length - 1; i++)
                        {
                            vals[z] = cols[i].Replace(',', ' ');
                            z++;
                        }
                        //line = ",".join([CustType, CategoryType, CategoryValue, DataType, vals[0], vals[1], vals[2], vals[3], vals[6], currency])
                        lineWrite = clean(custType) + "," + clean(categoryType) + "," + clean(categoryValue) + ","
                                    + clean(dataType) + "," + clean(vals[0]) + "," + clean(vals[1]) + "," + clean(vals[2])
                                    + "," + clean(vals[3]) + "," + clean(vals[6]) + "," + filesToProcess[x, 1];

                        if (!HeaderLine(line))
                        {
                            w.WriteLine(lineWrite);
                            w.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        w.Close();
        sw.Close();
        //Custom Code ends here
        
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    public bool HeaderLine(String line)
    { 
        return line.Contains("Stock Qty");
    }

    public string clean(string str)
    {
        if (str != null)
            return Regex.Replace(str,@"[""]","");
            //return str.Replace('"', ' ');
        else
            return "";
    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

}
```

}

Can anyone suggest what could have possibly gone wrong or maybe how to debug this code in order to understand the errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Your script component is not in Visual Basic.  It is in C#

Comment: Apologies, my bad, i wrote in a hurry

Answer (score 6):

Here's how you debug scripts in SSIS

- With the code open, put a breakpoint
- Close the code
- Run the package
- When the script starts running, it will open up a code window and you can walk through the code step by step

Comment: Thanks! I just discovered it was an access issue with local file paths.

Comment: Hi, the issue came up again, and I tried setting the breakpoints, but I'm unable to do so. There is also a small message saying Breakpoints cannot  be added in this location

Comment: add it on the line that has `public void main` and then you can step through

Comment: close all SSIS and C# code windows, then reopen and start

Comment: @user2673722 could you expand on the "access issue with local file paths"? I'm also struggling with this and debugging isn't helping - the breakpoints are never hit.

Comment: Such a straightforward problem with an easy solution.  It almost seems to easy to just follow your intuition with these things.  Thanks for the help to all of us new to SSIS!